# What would be the best way to cut/paste duplicate rows to the next sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an item list in Excel: 42k rows and 15 columns. A lot of items have been listed twice and some even thrice, as the product is the same but the seller is different.

What I want to do is check only 8 columns (a,b,c,d,f,h,i,k) to decide if the row is duplicate or not. If it has an exact match with another row for the respective 8 columns, I want to cut paste both/all the matching rows into the next sheet (all 15 columns) where I can manually merge/delete/separate depending on the item.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Have you attempted any part of it yet? What were the areas that you had issues with?

Comment: vba is not my cup of tea. looking for help

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that you need to help yourself first before SO will help you. Just because VBA isn't your cup doesn't mean you can't try.

Comment: I would not cut/paste. I would do the following. Create a new column with a value that concatenated your 8 columns. If I needed to restore the original sequence I would create a second new column holding the current row number. Manually sort sheet by first new column.  Write a macro to run down sheet comparing each row with the row above. If I got a match I would place a value in a third new column. Ctrl+DownArrow would to jump to the block of records requiring attention.

Comment: Keep in mind that people here are very happy to help - but only with actual programming questions, not whole scale 'please do this project for me' requests. That's what pay services are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone whos looking for a similar job to be done.

the numbers indicate the corresponding columns.

```
Sub MG10Oct47()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, c As Long, nRng As Range
Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For Each Dn In Rng
   oTxt = Join(Application.Index(Dn.Resize(, 12).Value, 0, Array(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12)), ",")
    If Not .Exists(oTxt) Then
        .Add oTxt, Dn
    Else
        If nRng Is Nothing Then Set nRng = Union(.Item(oTxt), Dn) Else Set nRng = Union(nRng, .Item(oTxt), Dn)
    End If
Next
If Not nRng Is Nothing Then
For Each Dn In nRng
    c = c + 1
    Sheets("sheet2").Cells(c, 1).Resize(, 16).Value = Dn.Resize(, 16).Value
Next Dn
nRng.EntireRow.Delete
End If
End With
End Sub
```

thanks to @MickG for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PivotTable in Tabular form and subtotals only on ColumnA, count of ColumnA in VALUES and all of Columns B, C, D, F, H, I and K for ROWS. Wherever the count is greater than `1`, drill down on that larger value. Each time you should be creating a sheet with just the entries determined to be multiple according to your criteria:

[image: SO33019442 example]

Though this is *copy*/paste rather than *cut*/paste.